# Debug logs for a failing apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

We have had a contractor develop a trigger for us that doesn't seem to be working in the way it should. Unfortunately, the contractor no longer works with us and we've been told by BMC support we need to provide them with the following info. Is anybody able to advise me on how I should go about this, please

"1. Debug logs when the status of an incident is closed"

"2. Ask a customer to add logs in the trigger which they have implemented and collect the logs when the trigger gets executed."

Is anybody able to guide me on how I could do this, please?

```
trigger COL_JIS_Set_Status_Closed on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c (before update) {
BMCServiceDesk__Status__c closedstatus = [Select Id from BMCServiceDesk__Status__c where Name = 'Closed' 
                                          and BMCServiceDesk__inactive__c = False limit 1];
    For (BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c inc : Trigger.New){
        if (inc.COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c == True && Trigger.oldMap.get(inc.id).COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c == False){
            inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c = closedstatus.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add `system.debug` to get some details. And use debug logs to get complete details.

Comment: Martin's answer is the right way to setup debugging.

However I'd just add that this looks like a very simple trigger.

Whenever the value of COL_JIS_Stop_SLA__c changes from **false** to **true** on an instance of BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c, then that record has it's BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c set to a value (a constant selected from the database).

What's your problem with it? Is it that the setting is not occurring when you expect or that the value that it is set to is not what you expect.

Comment: An incredibly small amount of BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c are not changing to the correct status. This trigger was built because a workflow rule would not do the job properly (we're told it stopped firing due to SOQL query limits exceeded), the trigger has improved things (more tickets have the correct status), but we're still getting BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c records that are not changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a debug log for the user at Setup > Monitoring > Logs > Debug Logs.

Then perform an update on the one of your objects to make the trigger fire, and the log will appear in the list below.

By "add logs" to the trigger, I assume they mean to add `system.debug()` statements, which will print values out into the debug log.